# Export Categories with their ids to another installation

Tags: category, import, export, dataflow, importexport

How can I export my categories and retain their ids? Magento dataflow exports categories by their ids instead of their names, but after using a script to copy categories to the new install, the ids where completely different.

Anyone know of an easy way to export it?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is by exporting the relevant category tables and importing them in your new database. I wouldn't recommend this practice, however. Magento is very finicky about its database relations making sense.

If you REALLY need the old ids to be retained it is a better idea to add an attribute to the categories in the new installation and have it store the old id in that attribute with an import script.